# Counting back dates to the last day of a month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following timeline in Excel:

```
       A               B              C               D
1    31-10-2017    30-11-2017     31-12-2017      01-05-2018
```

In **Row 1** the dates are calculated back based on the value entered in **Cell D1**. The other dates are always counted back to the **last day of the month**.
For this I use the following formula in **Cells A1:C1**

```
C1=DATE(YEAR(D1),MONTH(D1-1),)
```

This formula works fine for all dates **except** for the **first day of a month**. For example if I enter `01-01-2018` into **Cell D1** the value in **Cell C1** is `30-11-2017` and not `31-12-2017`.

Do you have any idea how I have to modify my formula so it always counts back to the l**ast day of a month** no matter if I enter the first day of a month or any other day into **Cell D1**.

Comment: EOMONTH is the function you need: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-eomonth-function

Comment: ...or you can use `=D1-DAY(D1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=DATE(YEAR(D1),MONTH(D1),0)`

Day 0 will drop the date value to the day before the first day of the month (your last day of previous month)

Comment: `DAY(0)` can be just `0` - the `DAY` function will just return 0 anyway.

Comment: I shouldn't just fire off 15 second answers, I need to proof read... Thanks, updated